# Simple way to hide the first button in the list of buttons in angular2 template?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

[image]

Here under the section, i have set of buttons, i always need to hide the first button in that list of buttons.How can i do that?

This is my html template

```
 <section class="list-group results" *ngIf="showSuggestions">
        <div class="typeahead-backdrop" (click)="hideSuggestions()"></div>
        <button  type="button" class="list-group-item"
          *ngFor="let result of results; let i = index;"
          [class.active]="markIsActive(i, result)"
          (click)="handleSelectSuggestion(result)">
          <span *ngIf="!taItemTpl"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> {{ result }}</span>
          <ng-template
            [ngTemplateOutlet]="taItemTpl"
            [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: {result: result, index: i} }"
          ></ng-template>
        </button>
      </section>
```

Is there any simple way to achieve this?Thanks in advance!

Comment: use < *ngFor="let result of result; let first=first" >< button *ngIf="!first">.. https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just add slice pipe to it, and first element won't appear

```
*ngFor="let result of results | slice:1"
```

Hope it will help you.